# How to list all Dir files in a ListBox in Android

Tags: android, list, delphi, get

How to list all Dir files in a ListBox ?
I tried this code in Windows and it worked, but it doesn't work in Android.

```
procedure ListFileDir(Path: string; FileList: TStrings);
 var
  SR: TSearchRec;
    begin
       if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
      begin
      repeat
     if (SR.Attr <> faDirectory) then
  begin
    FileList.Add(SR.Name);
     end;
    until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
   FindClose(SR);
 end;
end;

  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ListFileDir('sdcard/1/', ListBox1.Items);
 end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is for Windows only. For cross-platform development you should use `System.IOUtils` when working with files and folders.

Specifically, `TDirectory.GetFiles(Path)`

```
uses
  System.Types,
  System.IOUtils;

procedure ListFileDir(Path: string; FileList: TStrings);
var
  Files: TStringDynArray;
  s: string;
begin
  FileList.Clear;
  Files := TDirectory.GetFiles(Path);
  for s in Files do
    FileList.Items.Add(s);
end;
```

Comment: can u plz pass the code 4 me, its my 1st time dong cross-platform programming

Comment: You should fill a local stringlist and assign it to FileList or use `FileList.BeginUpdate` and `FileList.EndUpdate` before and after modify.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code for cross platform purposes is not your use of `FindFirst` and friends as such (`TDirectory.GetFiles` is just a thin wrapper over them), but the `'*.*'` construct - you need to use just `'*'` instead:

```
procedure ListFileDir(Path: string; FileList: TStrings);
const
  AllFilesMask = {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}'*.*'{$ELSE}'*'{$ENDIF};
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(Path + AllFilesMask, faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
  try
    repeat
      if (SR.Attr <> faDirectory) then
      begin
        FileList.Add(SR.Name);
      end;
    until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
  finally
    FindClose(SR);
  end;
end;
```